# cannot seem to get table header to display

Tags: reactjs

I have a table where I am feeding data into it from an api, the data is fetched correctly and displays properly for the table row and data which is part of the tbody but inside the thead I try to display a header but nothing seems to be displayed even though the data being passed to the header is being logged to the console. Can anyone see  my issue?

Component with table:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import secondsToMinutes from '../utils/utils';

function Table(props) {

    const styles = {
  
    div: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        margin: '0 auto',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
  },


};


    const [table, setTable] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      setTable(<table >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {props.headerData.map(header => {
              console.log("table header = ", header);
                {header.map((item, i) => {
                console.log("header item", item.name)
                return (<th 
                } key={i}>{item.name}</th>
            )})}
          })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.data.map((array, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              {array.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td key={i}>{item.nameValue} </td>
                  </tr>
                  )
              })}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>)
    }, [props.data, props.header]);


    return (
        <div style={styles.div}>
            {table}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: why do you want to save the table in the state?, why dont just return the table in jsx?

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from the outer `map()`.

Change the `thead` to:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        {
            props.headerData.map(header => {
                console.log("table header = ", header);
                return header.map((item, i) => {
                    console.log("header item", item.name)
                    return (<th key={i}>{item.name}</th>)
                })
            }}
        }
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Note the `return` before `header.map`

---

That said, you shouldn't save the DOM element to the `useState`. Rather save the data to the state, and then in your `return` render function render the `table`